# USB Cam: No space left on device (-28)

Tags: linux, usb-device

I'm developing a project with lichee pi zero. I want to connect usb cam to it and record video plus show on LCD.
At first step I built u-boot and kernel and write them on SD card. It worked fine. Then I connected usb cam to it. But it didn't recognize. So I searched and realized that I should change "OTG dir" in device tree. So I changed it to "host" to use it just as host.
Then I compiled device tree and replaced with original.
After that USB camera recognized but there was not appropriate driver for it. So I made some change in kernel menu config and I add v4l2, usb_video_class and some more to kernel and again I built the kernel.

After all of that usb camera recongized very well and driver set automatically.
At this point I have a bad error that I couldn't solve it for 2 weeks.

I'm using yavta to capture and save frames. I got it and I cross compiled it for my board.
at the end I I try yavta with USB camera on lichee pi.

my command:
`$ ./yavta --capture=25 --file=out.mjpeg /dev/video0`

output error:

```
Device /dev/video0 opened.
Device 'USB Camera' on 'usb-musb-hdrc.1.auto-1' (driver 'uvcvideo') supports video, capture, without mplanes.
Video format: MJPEG (47504a4d) 640x480 (stride 0) field none buffer size 614400
8 buffers requested.
length: 614400 offset: 0 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 0/0 mapped at address 0xb6d88000.
length: 614400 offset: 614400 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 1/0 mapped at address 0xb6cf2000.
length: 614400 offset: 1228800 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 2/0 mapped at address 0xb6c5c000.
length: 614400 offset: 1843200 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 3/0 mapped at address 0xb6bc6000.
length: 614400 offset: 2457600 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 4/0 mapped at address 0xb6b30000.
length: 614400 offset: 3072000 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 5/0 mapped at address 0xb6a9a000.
length: 614400 offset: 3686400 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 6/0 mapped at address 0xb6a04000.
length: 614400 offset: 4300800 timestamp type/source: mono/SoE
Buffer 7/0 mapped at address 0xb696e000.
[   79.878953] uvcvideo: Failed to submit URB 0 (-28).
Unable to start streaming: No space left on device (28).
8 buffers released.
```

Comment: Multiple results on search engines suggest that ENOSPC is an error borrowed to mean for uvcvideo (at least): "not enough bandwidth" (through the USB port).